# Access VBA simple save and clear routine for form error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to save and clear the contents an unbound form in MS Access. The saving part is working, however its not clearing the form.

If I understood it right, all of these should clear the form, for a new entry:

```
Me.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
Me.Refresh
```

another small Problem is, that the list won't requery, maybe that's the same problem idk.

```
Private Sub Speichern_Click()



Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_Sonderleistungen", dbOpenDynaset)



'rs!ID = Me.ID
rs!Leistungsart = Me!Leistungsart
rs!Datum = Me!Datum
rs!Linie = Me!Linie
rs!Schicht = Me!Schicht
rs!SchichtFuehrerNr = Me!Personal
rs!ReDatum = Me!ReDatum
rs!Kommentar = Me!Kommentar
rs!Bemerkung = Me!Bemerkung





Set rs = Nothing

Me.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
Me.Refresh


**Me.lstSonderleistungen.Requery**



End Sub
``


PS.: Its Access 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not `GoTo .. Last` for a unbound form, so you must clear the textboxes manually.

But why all this? Make the form bound, and you can replace all that code with a goto new record.

Comment: I used the use bound forms however I wanted to try something different, therefore the unbound form.

What do you mean by ```GoTo .. Last```?

Comment: Well, then you are about reinventing Access. There may be very good reasons for using unbound forms, but then move to an environment optimised for that, like Visual Studio and WinForms.